# Setting up 3rd party libraries environment for CMake on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, windows-10

I'm having problems with the "proper" way of installation third-party libraries for use with CMake projects (C++). For most of the time I haven't been bothering myself with this stuff and just hardcoding library paths in my `CMakeLists.txt`, but I really want to start using this properly.

I ultimately want to have something where I can just type, for example, `find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)` in a project and the library is there, found, and works perfectly.

What I have right now is I have a folder `C:\CMakeLibs` where I `--install` all 3rd party libraries, so for example there is `C:\CMakeLibs\SDL2` and in it, there are folders like `cmake`, `include`, `lib`, etc. Then I include the folder `C:\CMakeLibs\SDL2` in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` in system environment variables, so that CMake can find the `SDL2Config.cmake` file and there's no need for any `FindSDL2.cmake`. This way I can just type following code and it straight works, and is also probably the most portable for open-source projects.

```
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2main SDL2::SDL2-static)
```

My only concern here is that I have to manually add any new libraries to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. I'd like just have only `C:\CMakeLibs` as my `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and everything working fine. I could technically `--install` the libraries directly to `C:\CMakeLibs` but I fear of any possible incompatibilities when having all the different files in one shared folders, it doesn't feel like the best solutions.

I know this question might be one of those "without the best answers/based on opinion". I've been looking for solutions on internet for long time already, ever since I started using CMake, so I decided to just write this post here. I hope I described my problem clearly, English isn't my native language.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I use a completely different method that involves the having multiple simultaneous build trees for mostly the same source tree which is important to me because some third party dependencies required old versions of Qt and older compiler for one of my major projects but then a Qt-5.X version for my other projects. Each of these build trees are their own hierarchy of my code and libraries. All of this use a set of cmd.exe scripts that set environment variables where I launch cmake-gui from the cmd.exe window with the different environment setup. I do this at home and work for 12 years now.